# How do I copy files in Jolicloud from one drive to another

Tags: usb, jolicloud

I'm running Jolicloud 1.2 from a USB stick. I clicked the "run but don't install option" at the start up menu and then i created an account. It says I am logged in as guest mode.

How can I copy files from my original c:\ which is listed in the file manager to my usb stick. There's no button and drag and drop doesn't work

is there a way to get into terminal?

Is it perhaps restricted because I am a "guest"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, you can launch the file manager by downloading a file in google chrome and clicking "show in folder" when you right click on the file in the downloads page (ctrl+j in chrome gets you there)

I still don't know where to launch this from natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the *Local Apps ⇨ More Apps* to open a file browser (at least in Nautilus 2.30.1)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then type: `Nautilus` 
This will open the classic file browser.